# What does {NUMBER} mean in an LDAP filter?

Tags: jenkins, ldap, jenkins-plugins

I'm maintaining an LDAP filter that looks something like `(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))`, and am trying to understand what the `{0}` means.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this "curly braces with a number" syntax.  I've looked at the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515) defining LDAP search strings, at [the MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx), and [at the centos docs](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/CDS/ag/8.0/Finding_Directory_Entries-LDAP_Search_Filters.html), but none mention this syntax as far as I can tell.

EDIT:

It turns out, this is not part of the LDAP specification. It is an extension provided by the Jenkins LDAP plugin, and is equal to the username provided by the user when logging in.

Answer (score 4):

This syntax is a result of the jenkins LDAP plugin.  `{0}` will evaluate to the username inputed by the user trying to log in.

For future googlers:  This is not part of the LDAP protocol, but part of whatever application you're using.

[Source](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin)

Comment: No. It is also present in the UnboundID API, the Novell API, the Netscape API, and JNDI, to name only the APIs I'm familiar with. It isn't part of the *protocol*, but that's because the protocol doesn't define APIs, only the protocol.

Comment: There is nothing wrong this answer. Even though it's a common syntax used by several LDAP client implementations (you mentioned a few of them) it is not defined in the LDAP protocol.

Comment: @EJP I believe I clearly stated: "this is not part of the LDAP protocol, but part of whatever application you're using."  I understand that other applications have this syntax, I just didn't bother providing a complete list.  If you believe my answer is too terse, feel free to edit it.